# Mock keeps calling real function

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock a function. When I try to mock the function `core.use_cases.add_owner_to_place` the mock doesn't work. It keeps printing "Ouch".

I've tried to test `mocked_add_owner_to_place.called` and it returns False.

Does anyone know why it keeps using the real function even if I mock it?

**views.py:**

```
from core.use_cases import add_owner_to_place

class CreatePlace(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'place/create_place.html'
form_class = PlaceForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('place_list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    place = form.save()
    add_owner_to_place(place, self.request.user)
    return super(CreatePlace, self).form_valid(form)
```

**tests.py:**

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

@patch('core.use_cases.add_owner_to_place')
@patch('core.forms.PlaceForm.is_valid')
@patch('core.forms.PlaceForm.save')
def test_save_should_be_called(self, mocked_save, mocked_is_valid, mocked_add_owner_to_place):
    self.client.post(reverse('place_create'), data={})
    self.assertTrue(mocked_save.called)
```

**uses_cases.py:**

```
def add_owner_to_place(place, user):
    print('Ouch')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, searching around and looking some codes on github, I found out that I need to mock from the `view` even if the function belongs to the `use_cases` module.

So my code now is:

**tests.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

@patch('core.views.add_owner_to_place')
@patch('core.forms.PlaceForm.is_valid')
@patch('core.forms.PlaceForm.save')
def test_save_should_be_called(self, mocked_save, mocked_is_valid, mocked_add_owner_to_place):
    self.client.post(reverse('place_create'), data={})
    self.assertTrue(mocked_save.called)
```

I know that this works, but now I need to search why it works. I'll explain it when I figure it out.

Comment: The reason for this is explained fairly thoroughly in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)

Comment: For anyone looking to learn more, the following section is the most relevant: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch